# building a media pc from scrap parts

Tags: computer-building, sound-card, media-player, surround-sound

I am wanting to build a media pc from some old parts and i have a few questions as well.

My goals for the media center pc:

- blue ray
- 1080p
- watch youtube and other internet video
- work with my pre-existing surround sound and reciever 5.1 currently, (would like to have the ability to just add my two additional speakers for 7.1 later and not have to upgrade anything)

Those are the main features. I dont really care about cable tv. We do not have it and do not plan to have it.

**My main question is the fourth feature. How can i accomplish this?**

Currently i have my speakers connected into my reciever and all my devices are connected to my reciever and then the video from the reciever is connected to my tv and the audio plays through the speakers and the video through the tv (obviously).

My speakers have the "wirey" ends. (do not know a lot about speakers... lol).

**Would i just buy a sound card for the pc and then connect the output of the sound card to the reciever?**

My reciever has a place for optical and a few other spots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best case scenario would be to go Optical from PC to Optical on Receiver or HDMI from PC to HDMI to Receiver. Sound from HDMI stays with receiver and video is passed via HDMI from Receiver to TV.

Going with the HDMI route (assuming your video card supports it) will have an integrated sound controller that will pass the audio via the HDMI cable. I picked up a small Sony surround system who's amp has 5 HDMI inputs, 1 HDMI output. Works great!

Comment: Here is the card i have: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814130435 Does it support the sound controller thing you were talking about?

Comment: No, because it doesn't have HDMI. You would have to result to Optical from a onboard or separate sound card for best audio quality/clarity.

Comment: Never mind, i would still use the optical. You said it was the best case scenario.

Comment: I have another question about hdmi. The card i showed you does not have an hdmi output. If i were to buy a dvi to hdmi converter cable, would i lose any quality on the video? Or should i buy an hdmi output video card?

Comment: You're best off getting a video card that supports HDMI. On my media center htpc, I use Intel HD3000 for my graphics. It does a fine job for streaming videos and bluray playback. I use a ceton tuner card that can record/watch up to 4 channels simultaneously.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I am going to research the cable thing a little more. I am hoping to keep the same video card, considering it is a very good one. Thanks

Comment: You definitely can keep that card if you send your audio to the receiver a different method (optical).